# Are these parts compatible to build a quadrone?

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, first-robotics

I want to build a quaddrone from scratch, without using ready made controllers. I've read a lot about drones, how they fly and what essential parts they should have.

So I decided to make my own quaddrone with arduino micro-controller, Are **the following parts compatible and good to build a quadrone ?**

- Brushless DC motor RacingEdition (KV=2600,Weight: 28 grams,Battery: 2-4S lipo battery,Max.current: 23.2A, Max.power: 710W) [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32706910811.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.51d53c00LHcJuU)
- ESC (Continuous current: 30A,Instantaneous current (10 seconds): 35A,frequencies up to 48MHz) [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32950669122.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.51d53c00LHcJuU)
- Propellers (4730F Folding Propeller Blades,Material: plastic) [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32841765501.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.51d53c00LHcJuU)
- IMU sensor (Nine-axis module (three-axis gyroscope + three-axis acceleration + three-axis magnetic field) [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/GY-85-nine-axis-IMU-sensor-ITG3200-ITG3205-ADXL345-HMC5883L-module/173843276384?hash=item2879dde260:g:J9gAAOSwddpckZx-)
- Carbon Fiber/Aluminium frame [link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/ZMR250-3K-Carbon-Fiber-4-Axis-QAV250-FPV-Quadcopter-Mini-H-Quad-Drone-Frame-Kits/292822176614?epid=1895422269&hash=item442d8fd366:g:aMYAAOSwInxXNUjd&frcectupt=true)
- Arduino UNO
- Lipo Battery (3S 11.1 V, 4200mAh, 30C) [link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32718113056.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.22.67ce225dp9uyH3&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_7_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536%2Csearchweb201603_53%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=3438c1ff-ec7b-40d6-a022-1831f93a7c46-3&algo_pvid=3438c1ff-ec7b-40d6-a022-1831f93a7c46)

Also what about the RC controller (RC transimtter and receiver) could it be done using android mobile app and wireless module ?

I really appreciate your help ♥, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used an arduino for quadcopter so I'll leave that to someone else to answer. However given that flight controllers are so cheap maybe it would be worth starting with one just to make sure everything else works and to gain experience.

For the rest of the components.

- Frame looks good, I started with one of those. Easy to put together, quite robust and lots of space (although an UNO is much bigger than a normal flight controller, so that might be a challenge)
- Motors look good for the frame size
- ESCs look good
- Not sure about the propellers. I've not used folding ones before. Probably fine but check how they mount to the motors. They might be DJI specific mounting.
- Battery is about twice the size I would expect on a quad of this size. I'd look at something in the 1.8 - 2.2Ah range.

For the RC control there are lots of options which would work. It depends what you need in turns of range and latency. If you use a standard RC model's radio equipment then you get good range and good latency. Android with wireless module would be less range and higher latency but could still be find for your needs.

Edit:

Also checkout https://www.arducopter.co.uk/what-do-i-need.html good source on info on arduino based n-copters.

Comment: thx bro for helping me

Comment: @JamalAl-kelani You're welcome